# How can I get records from two tables that do not have any relation in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Table 1 (abc) with these columns

```
 ____________________________
|__id__|__userid__|__points__|
|__1__ |_____2____|____30____|
|__2__ |_____2____|____50____|
|__3__ |_____3___ |____40____|
```

Table 2 (xyz)

```
 ________________________________
|__id__|__userid__|__usedpoints__|
|__1__ |_____2____|______10______|
|__2__ |_____3____|______20______|
|__3__ |_____2___ |______15______|
```

How can I get records like this from these two tables?

```
 _________________________________________
|__userid__|__totalpoints__|__usedpoints__|
|____2____ |_______80______|______25______|
|____3____ |_______40______|______20______|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select u1.userid, sum(u1.points) as totalpoints, u2.usedpoints
from table1 u1
left join 
(
   select userid, sum(usedpoints) as usedpoints
   from table2
   group by userid
) u2 on u1.userid = u2.userid
group by u1.userid
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c172/6)

Comment: this query is not working properly. its giving me this.............
userid | totalpoints  | usedpoints
  2       |      160       |     50
  3       |       80        |     40